# Get the difference between NOW() and a date Time field in seconds

Tags: apex, datetime

I have a custom field (custom_field__c) on lead object and in my trigger i want to check difference between NOW() and current value of custom_field__c. And if difference is more than 5 seconds then do some action.

So for this requirement will below formula work 100% ? or are there any limitations or problems in it. Thanks for help:)

```
( NOW() - custom_field__c )*24*60*60
```

Also how to check if dateTime field is empty:
 Will custom_field__c == Null works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert the `datetime` to `Long` to calculate time difference. Refer [DateTime.getTime() method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm)

Like CurrentTime `DateTime.now().getTime()` will return `1490556040011L`

As per your requirement the logic should be like this:

```
if(Custom_Field__c !=null)
{
    Long customFieldLong = Custom_Field__c.getTime() ;
    Long currentDTLong = DateTime.now().getTime();
    Long milliseconds = currentDTLong - customFieldLong;
    Long seconds = milliseconds / 1000;
    if(seconds>5)
    //perform the desired action
}
```