# difference of two date time field in days and hours

Tags: process-builder, formula-field, date, time

How can I show the difference of two date time fields in days and hours. I am trying to do this in a formula field or process builder.

Example:  16/10/2021 11:00am - 15/10/2021 10:00am = 1 day 1 hour

Comment: hello Akash,  see the existing answer https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/166079/10073

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Akash,

Can you try the below?

```
IF(
CONTAINS( TEXT( End_Date_Time__c - Start_Date_Time__c ), '.' ),
IF(
DATEVALUE( End_Date_Time__c ) = DATEVALUE( Start_Date_Time__c ),
'0',
MID( TEXT( End_Date_Time__c - Start_Date_Time__c ), 0, FIND( '.', TEXT( End_Date_Time__c - Start_Date_Time__c ) ) - 1 )
)
& ' Day(s) ' &
TEXT( ROUND( VALUE( MID( TEXT( End_Date_Time__c - Start_Date_Time__c ), FIND( '.', TEXT( End_Date_Time__c - Start_Date_Time__c ) ), 18 ) ) * 24, 2 ) )
& ' Hour(s)',
TEXT( End_Date_Time__c - Start_Date_Time__c ) & ' Day(s) 0 Hours'
)
```

Let me know if you have any additional questions.

Comment: thanks it works. but now I am struggling to make it incremental like already present 1 day 1hrs + 1 day 2 hrs (like first_date_time_diff + above calculation). is it possible to do it in same formula field?

Comment: Akash, you can adjust the formula as you need. But, it is better to avoid adding additional logic to the formula. Else, the run time will increase a lot.